# Add request interceptors to specific calls

Tags: retrofit

I'm currently trying to figure out which options does retrofit offer to add an interceptor only to specific calls.

**Background & use cases**

I'm currently using retrofit 1.9
The use case is pretty simple. Imagine a user who needs to login and get a session token. There is a call.

```
/**
 * Call the backend and request a session token
 */
@POST("auht_endpoint")
Observable<Session> login(...);
```

All other calls will require a token from the above session in the form of a request header. In other words, all subsequent calls will have a header which provides the session token to the backend.

**My question**

Is there a simple way of adding this header only to specific calls through interceptors?

**What I've tried so far**

- Obviously the easiest approach was to add the `@Header` annotation to the specific calls and providing the token as a parameter
- I guess one can inspect the url in the request inside the interceptor. Not very flexible.
- Create different rest adapters with different interceptors. I heard you should avoid creating several instances of the rest adapter for performance reasons.

**Additional info**

- I'm not committed to interceptors, I would use other solutions
- I've said I'm using retrofit 1.9, but I'd be also interested in a way to do it with retrofit 2.x

Answer (score 1):

*Please note this is not an answer, comment box was too small.*

I've recently had this problem and I came up to the same possible solutions as you.

- First of all I put aside double adapters - thats a last resort.
- @Header field seems ok, bacause you explicitly define that this specific request needs authorization. However it's kinda boring to use.
- Url inspection in interceptor looks "ugly", but I've decided to go with that. I mean if **all** requests from a one specific endpoint need that authorization header then what's the problem?

I had two other ideas:

- Somehow dynamically replace/modify okHttpClient which is used with Retrofit. After some tests I figured that it's not possible.
- Maybe create some custom annotation @AddAuthorizationHeader to the call definition, which will do everything for you, but I guess it wouldn't be possible either.

And in this matter Retrofit 2.x doesn't bring anything new.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. Will definitely take a look at that!